# How do I save the results of a For loop as individual items in a list?

Tags: python

I am currently writing an encryption program for a school project and I'm using an 8 character ASCII key to calculate the offset factor. I randomly generate 8 numbers between 33 and 126 and convert them into ASCII characters. I'm using a `for` loop for this. Currently it just prints each character individually, but I would like it to save each character as an item in a list for me to use later. My code right now is this:

```
def characterkey():
    print("Your 8 character key is: ")
    for i in range(1,8):                
        randint=random.randrange(33,127)
        asciiletter=str(chr(randint))   
        print(asciiletter, end="")      
    randint=random.randrange(33,127) 
    asciiletter=str(chr(randint))    
    return asciiletter
```

I'd like to have each outcome stored into a variable in a list, so that all 8 characters are in a list.

Comment: Last 3 lines in your code create 8th character, isn't it? Why you create `7` characters *in a loop* and then another `1` out of them? I guess you thought that your loop will iterate over number `1` to `8` and you were surprised that it gave only `7` characters, so you added `1` extra. `(range(1, 8)` means from `1` inclusive to `8` *exclusive*, or `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7` for your information)

Answer (score 4):

With a list comprehension:

```
asciiletters = [chr(random.randrange(33,127)) for i in range(8)]
```

Note that there's no need for `str`.

Less advanced, and closer to your code:

```
asciiletters = []
for i in range(8):
    randint = random.randrange(33, 127)
    asciiletter = chr(randint)
    asciiletters.append(asciiletter)
```

Comment: Sorry, this create only 7-characters list. Use `range(8)` instead of `range(1:8)`,

Comment: @MarianD thanks, I just copied that from OP without thinking.

Comment: It's OK - in my comment I wrote `range(1:8)` instead of `range(1, 8)` :-)

Comment: Thanks for the help, the reason why i used 7 iterations in a loop and then 1 after the loop was because when i use return with an 8 iteration loop as just 'return' it prints 'None' and i dont want that